# TypeError: destroyWindow() missing required argument 'winname' (pos 1)

Tags: python, opencv

the programming is running correctly but after that it show and error which says that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python programs/unwired learning/face detection/2.py", line 19, in <module>
    cv2.destroyWindow()
TypeError: destroyWindow() missing required argument 'winname' (pos 1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAEft.png)

Comment: In the future please cut & paste your code into your posts. In this case your problem is simple (see gilad enini's answer below) but future problems might require people to run your code & they wont bother if they cant just cut & paste it.

Comment: helpful links: [tour], [ask], [mre]. error messages are designed to be read and understood, or at least googled. if you have trouble understanding "missing required argument", perhaps that's something to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

destroy window (notice the singular tense) destroys a specific window by title argument. either change to `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` or `cv2.destroyWindow('hahaha')`